# Inline generators do not work? (arrow-function)

Tags: javascript, generator, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

In ES6 we can replace in-line function:

```
function(param){        
}
```

with this:

```
param=>{    
}
```

Does this no longer work with ES6 generators? Why can't we do something like:

```
param*=>{   
}
```

to provide an in-line generator function? I thought it would be a given, but nothing like this seems to work.

Am I missing something about in-line use of generators, or is it really that ES6 generators are 2 steps forward and 1 step back?

Comment: @CodeiSir: I've flagged this question for merging into the duplicate, you can do so as well if you want (please don't copy it). However, I don't think your answer doesn't contain an explanation for *why* arrows cannot be generators either - it only states *that* they cannot.